# Project geocoordinates point into SVG generated map

Tags: svg, geolocation, geometry

I have an SVG file representing a world area.
How could i project real-world geo-coordinates (IE: a specific point) on such SVG? 
What I need to do is plot points, I guess it is a matter of transforming geo coordinates into the SVG reference system.

Comment: If you already have an SVG map (that is, you're not generating one on the fly), you can't project coordinates onto the map without knowing that map's projection (e.g., Mercator), the coordinate reference system it uses (e.g., WGS84) and other parameters.

Comment: thans @PeterO. - I actually found out a way. I have the 4 N S W E geo coordinates of the projected area, and since it is a small area I can simply do a proportion without considering the earth curve:
x = map_pixels ( lat_input - lat_min ) / ( lat_max - lat_min)
were lat min and max are the bounds of my area in geographical system